# Laravel Web.php Route using multiple params using slug instead of the ID

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to show a url like this

> http://localhost/rumah-subsidi/disewa/area/condet

Here is my web.php route

```
Route::get('/{subCategory:slug}/{type:slug}/area/{complex:slug}'
[ComplexController::class,'index'])->name('home.complex');
```

Here is the controller

```
public function index(SubCategory $subCategory,Type $type,Complex $complex){
    dd($complex);
}
```

If I use "ID" as main parameter then it has no problem. Like this one

> http://localhost/4/2/area/31

This one is working fine. Whenever I change into slug it does not work and getting this following error

> Call to undefined method App\Models\SubCategory::types()

The weird thing, I use something like {model:field} and it works if using for singular. But for multiples. It wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel is scoping the binding when you do this:

> "When using a custom keyed implicit binding as a **nested** route parameter, Laravel will automatically scope the query to retrieve the **nested** model by its parent using conventions to guess the relationship name on the parent"

You can disable this feature on the route definition:

```
Route::get('/{subCategory:slug}/{type:slug}/area/{complex:slug}', [ComplexController::class,'index'])
    ->withoutScopedBindings()
    ->name('home.complex');
```

[Laravel 10.x Docs - Routing - Implicit Model Binding - Custom Keys & Scoping](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#implicit-model-binding-scoping) - `withoutScopedBindings`